# JPA - One-to-many annotation and id generation

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many

I'm using the following technology stack: Websphere liberty, JPA/Eclipselink.

I have to types of entites:

```
Employer
Employee
```

They are in one-to-many relationship, that is an `Employee` has az `Employer`, and an `Employer` has `Employees`.

I've set the `CASCADE_TYPE` annotation, so when I persist an `Empoyer`, all of its `Empoyees` are persisted as well.

I use the following code:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.merge(anEmpoyer);
//some application logic
//em.flush();
enter code here
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

What I'm curious about, it how the (generated) ids of the entites get filled?

When calling `merge`, I can see the id of `anEmployer` is filled, but the ids of the various `Employee`s are not.

When I call `flush`, I can see the `INSERT` statements running, but still, only the id of the `anEmloyer` is filled.

After calling `commit` all of the ids are filled.

My question is: how exactly JPA (Eclipselink) handles id filling? Is there a way to get all of the ids before `commit` (without creating another transaction)?

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: are you using jpa with instrumentation?

Comment: Yes, sorry; I forgot to mention that - updated the question. (BTW: why does it matter?)

Comment: what you could try is ask for one of the "missing" ID's before the commit happens (via method call). If you were using instrumentation eclipselink might then initiailise that value and provide it back. If instrumentation is not available I don't think this would happen. Also another mistake dev's make is they see the id is null when debugging the class (variable is null) but don't realise that it will not be null if they call say "getId" as jpa has instrumented around tha tmethod call

Comment: I tried calling getId, but got 0 :-(

Comment: That would be expected - if you don't have instrumentation. Is your Refernece type? Generally speaking, it is a good idea to make your key reference type

Comment: No; its a simple Long object

Comment: Are you checking the managed instance?  I expect Eclipselink to populate IDs on all managed instances after the flush, but merge returns a managed instance instead of making what you pass it managed.

Comment: Yes, I check the managed instance instead of the passed one

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve any generated keys by creating a @PostPersist callback method. From my reading, any generated keys should be available - at the latest - after flush i.e. before commit.

From the JPA 2 specification:

> The PostPersist and PostRemove callback methods are invoked for an
>   entity after the entity has been made persistent or removed. These
>   callbacks will also be invoked on all entities to which these
>   operations are cascaded. The PostPersist and PostRemove methods will
>   be invoked after the database insert and delete operations
>   respectively. These database operations may occur directly after the
>   persist, merge, or remove operations have been invoked or they may
>   occur directly after a flush operation has occurred (which may be at
>   the end of the transaction). **Generated primary key values are
>   available in the PostPersist method.**